# Where may be an error in the second DAO class, although I'm using the same algorithm, which is working fine in my first DAO class? (Spring JDBC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

**Unworking case:**

*In the unworking case the method always returns bean with null values ​​in*

**table:**

int- matrix_id; int user_id; varchar(45) matrix_name; int matrix_length;

**MatrixDAO:**

```
    package com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO;

import com.calango.DAOLayer.model.Matrix;

/**
 *
 * @author Calango
 */
public interface MatrixDAO {
    public Matrix findByID(int id);
    public String findMatrixNameById(int matrixId);
    public int getMatrixLength(int matrix_id);
    public void insertRecord(Matrix inserObject);
    public int findIdByName(String matrixName);
}
```

**JdbcMatrixDAO:**

```
package com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.impl;

import com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.MatrixDAO;
import com.calango.DAOLayer.model.Matrix;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

/**
 *
 * @author Calango
 */
public class JdbcMatrixDAO implements MatrixDAO{
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Matrix findByID(int matrixId) {
        String sqlForID = "SELECT * FROM matrix WHERE matrix_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        Matrix matrix = (Matrix)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        sqlForID, new Object[] { matrixId }, 
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Matrix.class));
        return matrix;
    }

    @Override
    public String findMatrixNameById(int matrixId){return findByID(matrixId).getMatrixName();}

    @Override
    public int getMatrixLength(int matrixId){return findByID(matrixId).getMatrixLength();}

    @Override
    public void insertRecord(Matrix insertObject) {
        String insertMatrix = "INSERT INTO matrix (user_id, matrix_name, matrix_length) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.update(insertMatrix, new Object[] { insertObject.getUserId(),
            insertObject.getMatrixName(),insertObject.getMatrixLength()
    });
    }

    @Override
    public int findIdByName(String matrixName) {
        String sqlForName = "SELECT matrix_id FROM matrix WHERE matrix_name = ?";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        Matrix matrix = (Matrix)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        sqlForName, new Object[] { matrixName }, 
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Matrix.class));
        return matrix.getMatrixId();
    }
}
```

**Spring-database.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>config.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="historyDAO" class="com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.impl.JdbcHistoryDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="elementsDAO" class="com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.impl.JdbcElementsDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="matrixDAO" class="com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.impl.JdbcMatrixDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>        

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${DB_DRIVER}" />
        <property name="url" value="${DB_CONNECTION}" />
        <property name="username" value="${DB_USER}" />
        <property name="password" value="${DB_PASSWORD}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**I'm calling:**

```
        ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-database.xml");
int matrixID = 4;
JdbcMatrixDAO matrixDAO = (JdbcMatrixDAO) context.getBean("matrixDAO");
String matrixName = matrixDAO.findMatrixNameById(matrixID);
```

**Matrix**

```
package com.calango.DAOLayer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author Calango
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="matrix")
public class Matrix implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "matrix_id", nullable = false)   
    int matrixId;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    int userId;
    @Column(name = "matrix_name")        
    String matrixName;
    @Column(name = "matrix_length")
    int matrixLength;

    public Matrix(){}

    public Matrix(int matrixId, int userId, String matrixName, int matrixLength){
        this.matrixId = matrixId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.matrixName = matrixName;
        this.matrixLength = matrixLength;
    }

    public int getMatrixId() {
        return matrixId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getMatrixName() {
        return matrixName;
    }

    public int getMatrixLength() {
        return matrixLength;
    }
}
```

**working case**

**history**

```
package com.calango.DAOLayer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Calango
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="history")
public class History implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "history_id", nullable = false)        
    int historyId;
    @Column(name = "matrix1_id")
    int matrix1Id;
    @Column(name = "matrix2_id")
    int matrix2Id;
    @Column(name = "matrix_result_id")
    int matrixResultId;
    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)        
    Timestamp date;

    public History(){}

    public History
        (int historyId, int matrix1ID, int matrix2ID, 
                int matrixResultID, Timestamp date) {
        this.historyId = historyId;
        this.matrix1Id = matrix1ID;
        this.matrix2Id = matrix2ID;
        this.matrixResultId = matrixResultID;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getHistoryId() {
        return historyId;
    }    

    public int getMatrix1Id() {
        return matrix1Id;
    }

    public int getMatrix2Id() {
        return matrix2Id;
    }

    public int getMatrixResultId() {
        return matrixResultId;
    }

    public Timestamp getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setHistoryId(int historyId) {
        this.historyId = historyId;
    }

    public void setMatrix1Id(int matrix1Id) {
        this.matrix1Id = matrix1Id;
    }

    public void setMatrix2Id(int matrix2Id) {
        this.matrix2Id = matrix2Id;
    }

    public void setMatrixResultId(int matrixResultId) {
        this.matrixResultId = matrixResultId;
    }

    public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**HistoryDAO**

```
package com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO;

import com.calango.DAOLayer.model.History;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Calango
 */
public interface HistoryDAO {
    public History findByID(int id);
    public int findIdByDate(String date);
    public List<String> getDatesList();
    public void insertHistory(History insertObject);
}
```

**JdbcHistoryDAO**

```
package com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.impl;

import com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO.HistoryDAO;
import com.calango.DAOLayer.model.History;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

/**
 *
 * @author Calango
 */
public class JdbcHistoryDAO implements HistoryDAO{
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public History findByID(int historyId) {
        String sqlForID = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE history_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        History history = (History)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sqlForID, new Object[] { historyId }, 
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(History.class));
        return history;
    }

    @Override
    public int findIdByDate(String date) {
        try{
        String sqlForDate = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE date = ?";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        History history = (History)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sqlForDate, new Object[] { date }, 
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(History.class));
        return history.getMatrix1Id();
        }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex){
            System.out.println("No date has been found: "+date);
            return 1;
        }
        //Logger.getLogger(JdbcHistoryDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, "No id was found by this date");    
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getDatesList(){
        String sqlForDates = "SELECT date FROM history";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        List<String> dates = 
                (List<String>)jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlForDates,String.class);
        return dates;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertHistory(History insertObject) {
        String insertHistorySql = "INSERT INTO history (matrix1_id, matrix2_id, matrix_result_id, date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, NOW())"; 
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.update(insertHistorySql, new Object[] { insertObject.getMatrix1Id(),
                    insertObject.getMatrix2Id(),insertObject.getMatrixResultId()
        });
    }
}
```

**calling**

```
ApplicationContext context = 
     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-database.xml");
JdbcHistoryDAO historyDAO = (JdbcHistoryDAO) context.getBean("historyDAO");
String selectedDate = "2014-05-01 16:10:09.0";
int matrixID = historyDAO.findIdByDate(selectedDate);
```

Comment: 01) Never use uppercase characters in the package names.
02) Create the JdbcTemplate in XML or in your constructor just once.
03) YOu are receiving null for Matrix because you never did an insertion for that record/entity before

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In accordance with clause 3 I thought so too, but after checking the database, I was convinced that this record is existing...

Comment: Your code is "complex", why you are using the BeanPropertyRowMapper? Are you sure each property name matches with each table's field? I would suggest create your own customized RowMapper<T>

Comment: I was too stubborn. I wanted to do it with BeanPropertyRowMapper, because I thought that it would be nicer and less to write. I was sure that each property name matches with each table's field. But as it turned out, that somewhere something is not the same ... Thank you very much. In accordance with clause 1, then, if the package name consists of several words then write them through "_"? e.g. dao_layer

Comment: BeanPropertyRowMapper has only sense when you have the complete control of the Class/properties according with Table/fields, but I suggest you strongly use RowMapper, more easier and flexible to **changes**. About 01 do not use: package com.calango.DAOLayer.DAO;, use instead: package com.calango.daolayer.dao;

Comment: BTW: For the JdbcTemplate, declare it how an instance variable for each DAO class and use the constructor to initialize it through DI. In XML you can define the JdbcTemplate how a bean once and inject right there the DataSource, in this way all your DAO classes do not use the DataSource anymore, since it was defined and injected into the JdbcTemplate through XML. Therefore your DAO classes now **only** need the JdbcTemplate.